# How do I find the horizontal/vertical asymptotes of an equation, if any?

Tags: calculus

I have the function $$f(x)=\frac{2x^2}{x^2-1}$$

and I need to find the horizontal and vertical asymptotes if any exist. The problem is I'm completely lost. The only thing I know is that the domain restrictions are $x\ne1, x\ne-1$. That only tells me there's a hole in the function though.

I know how to find asymptotes with problems like $\lim\limits_{x\to5}$ -- it would be a horizontal asymptote at $x=5$. I just don't understand how to do this problem. I think it has something to do with infinity but I'm not sure how to even figure that out.

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366442/limit-of-polynomial-division-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracfngn/3366457#3366457) for the horizontal asymptote.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

- $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} \frac{2x^2}{x^2-1} =2$

therefore $y=2$ in an horizontal asymptote and since $x^2-1=0 \implies x=\pm 1$ and

- $\lim_{x\to 1^+} \frac{2x^2}{x^2-1} =\infty$
- $\lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{2x^2}{x^2-1} =-\infty$
- $\lim_{x\to -1^+} \frac{2x^2}{x^2-1} =-\infty$
- $\lim_{x\to -1^-} \frac{2x^2}{x^2-1} =\infty$

therefore $x=-1$ and $x=1$ are vertical asymptotes.

Comment: I must be more lost than I thought because I'm not seeing how you get 2 in the first step. I'm also not seeing how you get +- infinity as x approaches 1/-1 just by looking at the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Try sketching the curve. What happens *near* the "holes" in the domain? What happens when $x$ is large? When $x$ is negative and far from $0$? You can think about those things numerically or with some algebra.

When you see the picture and understand what is going on you can write things out more formally with limits, but that's not where you should begin with a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to write rational functions on this form:

$\begin{cases}
f(x)=\dfrac{2x^2}{x^2-1}=2-\dfrac 1{x+1}+\dfrac 1{x-1}\\\\
g(x)=\dfrac{2x^3+9x^2+4x+10}{x^2+3x-4}=(2x+3)-\dfrac 2{x+4}+\dfrac 5{x-1}\end{cases}$

There are two types of asymptotic behaviour for a rational function:

- Asymptotic behaviour in the neighbourhood of a single point or pole:

Whenever your function has a pole at $x_0$, i.e. terms with denominators $\dfrac 1{(x-x_0)^m}$ the function takes $\pm\infty$ values depending on the oddness of $m$ when $x$ becomes close to $x_0$.

In this case we say that the line whose equation is $x=x_0$ is a vertical asymptote.

$f$ has vertical asymptotes $x=1$ and $x=-1$ and $g$ has vertical asymptotes $x=-4$ and $x=1$

- Asymptotic behaviour at infinity:

This time we are interested in the values of the function whenever $x\to\pm\infty$

For $f$ we have $f(x)\to 2$ and we say that the line $y=2$ is an horizontal asymptote.

But you can as well have asymptotes with any slope, for instance $g(x)$ behaves like $2x+3$ at infinity thus we say that the line $y=2x+3$ is an asymptote for $g$.

Note that asymptotic behaviour at infinity may not always be a straight line, for instance $h(x)=x^2-\frac 1x$ is asymptotic to the parabola $y=x^2$.

We just give a special preference to straight lines, because they are simple objects.